# JavaFX: Populate a tableview using map

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml

I'm starting to learn JavaFX and I want to populate my tableview with data from my database. I've learned that I could use map to build data but it didn't work. The tableview just shows the columns' name but no rows.

Here is my code:

#### Main.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

#### MainWindowControl.java

```
package application;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.MapValueFactory;

public class MainWindowController {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Map<Integer, String>> tableView = new TableView<>(generateDataInMap());

    final static Integer first = 1;

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from myTable");

        int col = rSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

        for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
            rSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from myTable");
            Integer key = 1;
            String name = rSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
            TableColumn<Map<Integer, String>, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>(name);
            tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(key));
            tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
        }
    }

    private ObservableList<Map<Integer, String>> generateDataInMap(){
        Connection connection = null;
        ObservableList<Map<Integer, String>> alldata = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from myTable");

            int col = rSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
            while(rSet.next()) {
                Map<Integer, String> dataRow = new HashMap<>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
                    String value = rSet.getString(i);
                    dataRow.put(i, value);
                }
                alldata.add(dataRow);
            }

            connection.close();
            return alldata;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="255.0" prefWidth="427.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainWindowController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="359.0" />
      <Button layoutX="186.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openDatabase" text="Load Data" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Do you know where the bugs in my code are? I'm trying to simulate the function of SQLiteStudio that when I choose a database, the data will populate the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `TableView` in the initializer of the controller class. This `TableView` is filled with data but the instance will never be displayed in a scene since `FXMLLoader` creates the one from the fxml.

Do initialisations like this in the `initialize()` method. This method is run by `FXMLLoader` after all objects have been injected making the `tableView` instance shown on screen accessible.

#### Additional notes:

- You pass `key` which is always `1` to the value factory. Instead you should use `i`.
- You requery the db for every column always fetching every single row in the table. This is very inefficient. Just execute the query a single time. Consider using the result for both initializing rows and columns.
- Consider seperating data access and view. You could do this by passing data to the controller, see [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)

```
@FXML
private TableView<Map<Integer, String>> tableView;

@FXML
private void initialize() throws Exception {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
         ResultSet rSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from myTable");
         openDatabase(rSet);
         tableView.setItems(generateDataInMap(rSet));
    }
    // TODO: Exception handling???
}

private void openDatabase(ResultSet rSet) throws SQLException {
    final ResultSetMetaData metadata = rSet.getMetaData();
    final int col = metadata.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
        String name = metadata.getColumnName(i);
        TableColumn<Map<Integer, String>, String> tableColumn = new TableColumn<>(name);
        tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(i));
        tableView.getColumns().add(tableColumn);
    }
}

private ObservableList<Map<Integer, String>> generateDataInMap(ResultSet rSet) {
    ObservableList<Map<Integer, String>> alldata = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    final int col = rSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    while(rSet.next()) {
        Map<Integer, String> dataRow = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
            String value = rSet.getString(i);
            dataRow.put(i, value);
        }
        alldata.add(dataRow);
    }

    return alldata;
}
```

Note that the above modified code version requires you to remove the `onAction` event handler but since adding the rows but not initializing the columns makes little sense I moved the call to the `initialize` method and modified the signature in a way that does not allow you to use it as a `EventHandler` anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice exactly solved my problem.                     I have another question that the eclipse gives me a warning in sentence " tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory(i));".                   Could you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: @方致远 Probably a warning because of the raw type used. Does specifying the type parameter fix this `tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory<String>(i));`?

Comment: I did this yesterday before I ask you for help. The eclipse gave me an error that `The method setCellValueFactory(Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map<Integer,String>,String>,ObservableValue<String>>) in the type TableColumn<Map<Integer,String>,String> is not applicable for the arguments (MapValueFactory<String>)` I have read the sorce code but I still don't know what should I do.

Comment: You're right. `MapValueFactory` (unfortunately) requires a raw `Map`, so one way or another you'll have to use a raw type. I'd just ignore the warning in this case. Just be sure never to put anything other than `String`s in the map. Otherwise this may yield `ClassCastException`s when other `TableColumn` properties are used with a custom class...

Comment: Thank for your reply. I think I can finish my programme with your suggestions.